# Applications of Theoretical Computer Science in Information Theory

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, it.information-theory, application-of-theory

Inspired by this question:
[Information Theory used to prove neat combinatorial statements?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/information-theory-used-to-prove-neat-combinatorial-statements)

Are there any nice applications of theoretical computer science in information theory (the other way has nice applications such as use of coding theory/Kolmogorov complexity in TCS)